# How to get a guest token for embedding a chart in Apache Superset

Tags: api, apache-superset

The Apache-Superset [swagger doc](https://superset.apache.org/docs/api/) for the guest_token API shows the following payload for the POST request:

[image]

I used it successfully from the following Python code snippet from their example included in the source:

```
body = {
    "resources": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "type": "dashboard"
        }
    ],
    "rls": [
    ],
    "user": {
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Doe",
        "username": "johnd"
    }
}
```

However, the documentation does not give any details on what other resource types besides "dashboard" are available. Can I directly embed a chart? I could have tried the "chart" but there is no documented way to obtain an embedded-id for a chart similar to the procedure that they describe for a dashboard.

To summarize, can I directly embed a chart too similar to a dashboard by this API and embedded sdk?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [source](https://github.com/apache/superset/blob/0b31b2cb877ce629c4f346ea434cd02c4a8a469b/superset/security/guest_token.py#L30-L31), the only accepted resource-type for guest tokens is `dashboard`:

```
class GuestTokenResourceType(Enum):
  DASHBOARD = "dashboard"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah.  Worse case, you could create a 1-chart Dashboard, and embed that.